# How to do Conditionals in React-Native (if else)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the best way for putting if statements in React-Native? The below is an example of what does not work.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Spinner isVisible={this.state.isVisible} size={100} type={'Wave'} color={"#FFFFFF"}/>
        </View>
        if (this.state.isVisible !== true) {
          <View>
            <Text style={{color: '#FFF'}}> Your Account Balance is 100 </Text>
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I guess, those are more specific to React, not React-Native.  Even though they are very similar I have not been able to find a question regarding conditionals in React-Native specifically.

Comment: I think if you try what's proposed in the linked question, you might find it answers your question.

Comment: Both React and React Native use JSX, so you can use the patterns described in the other questions as well.

Comment: You can use a ternary operator inside curly braces. e.g. <View>{bool ? <Text /> : <View />}</View> or have a block of if statements outside of your return and then simply do <View>{pickedComponent}</View> where pickedComponent = <SomeComponent /> inside of an if block